# I can't run tor via terminal after installed it(also from terminal)

Tags: tor

I kept seeing this out put

```
~$ tor
Nov 03 00:47:48.405 [notice] Tor 0.2.9.11 (git-aa8950022562be76) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g and Zlib 1.2.8.
Nov 03 00:47:48.405 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Nov 03 00:47:48.405 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Nov 03 00:47:48.407 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Nov 03 00:47:48.407 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Nov 03 00:47:48.407 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Nov 03 00:47:48.407 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

Comment: Please run `pgrep -l tor` and `netstat -lnp | grep 9050`. And add the output to your question. If the output of `netstat` dosen't include the process name run it as root, ie `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 9050`. `pgrep` will look up processes based on name. `netstat` is used to print network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, masquerade connections, and multicast memberships.

Comment: run `sudo lsof -i :9050` to see who or what is using that port

Comment: Looks as if it is already running. FWIW, IMHO, best to run the tor browser - pre-compiled and pre-configured. https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Comment: here is an out put sir




`~$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 9050
[sudo] password for fire-exit: 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9050          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6360/tor        
`

Comment: and this is another one


`~$ sudo lsof -i :9050
COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
tor     6360 debian-tor    6u  IPv4 658082      0t0  TCP localhost:9050 (LISTEN)`